# How do I get Algolia to index html list items?

Tags: jekyll, algolia

Currently, Algolia doesn't let me search for text inside the "li" tags in my jekyll site. I tried adding "-li" to config.yml but that didn't do it.

Has anyone dealt with this before? Thank you!

Comment: Some repository url please.

Comment: Is `record_css_selector: 'p,ul'` does the trick ? Reference: https://github.com/algolia/algoliasearch-jekyll#record_css_selector